# How to disable input source alternate switch keybinding?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Oneliner question:
How to get rid of the input source alternate switch shortcut?

Full question:

I use 2 keyboard inputs: "azerty" and "bépo" (French).
To switch between them, I can use "Super+Espace" or "Alt droite" (Alt gr). I don't want to use the "Alt gr" shortcut.

In gnome-control-center, I can edit the Super+Espace shortcut, but not "Alt gr".

`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source`
gives me 
`['<Super>space']`

I don't find anything else related to an alternate input shortcut with

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
```

More details:
Dell XPS 15
Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Same problem with embedded keyboard and external TypeMatrix keyboard

Comment: Hi, can you run `xev` command and then press AltGr and post the out put?

Comment: Hi, running `xev`

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0x193, subw 0x0, time 6663995, (77,693), root:(2033,759),
    state 0x2010, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Comment: KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0x193, subw 0x0, time 6664027, (77,693), root:(2033,759),
    state 0x2090, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Comment: ok do you have gnome tweaks installed?? Please run and produce the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: yes gnome-tweaks and gnome-tweak-tool installed. `['grp:toggle', 'grp_led:scroll']`

Comment: 0k..grp:toggle is the one.. right alt.. you can remove it or go to tweaks.. keyboard.. switch layout and uncheck..

Comment: to remove layout switching either do it in graphical way via gnome-tweaks or run `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['grp_led:scroll']"` https://i.stack.imgur.com/JecvK.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` produces `['grp:toggle', 'grp_led:scroll']`

Deleting "grp:toggle" solves the problem.

Run `dconf-editor` > desktop > input-sources > xkb-options. Delete 'grp:toggle'.

Thank you [PRATAP](https://askubuntu.com/users/739431/pratap)

Comment: If you don't have `dconf-editor`, just type: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['grp_led:scroll']"`.